# Memory leak by calling initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate of iOS on ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nsdate

When I call `initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:` like

```
NSDate * newDate = [date initWithTimeInterval:-7*24*60*60 sinceDate:date];
```

I get a memory leak. When I fix it like:

```
NSDate * newDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:-7*24*60*60 sinceDate:date];
```

I think no memory leak occurred. My question is why the former description causes a memory leak. Does it hold a strong reference? Or change the reference count?

Comment: Interesting question - I edited your post a bit and I hope that makes it more clear. If I got something wrong let me know.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want to say. Now I am checking memory leaks with  Instruments. It looks extra retain event exists.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show more code? How do you init date in the first example?
`initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:` is a constructor, so if you've already initialised data you must not call any `init...` method again for this variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That code is just example but I presume `date` is initialized by something like `init...`. So do you think I should use `dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:` instead of `initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:`?

Comment: @chabashilah, you definitely have to use `dateWithTimeInterval:sinceData:`.

Comment: @chabashilah, one more thing: you also can use `NSDate * newDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:-7*24*60*60 sinceDate:date];` The rule: don't call constructor `init...` method twice!